# How to remove all whitespaces in string and get exactly one number?( Python)

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string. For example:

```
str=     '\n                                    4 420 700 – 6 219 000 \n        '
```

or

```
'\n  4\xa0420\xa0700 – 6\xa0219\xa0000\xa0 \n'
```

In this case I would like get number: `4420700`. But any number can be there. It would be `3 333 999 233`, for example.

I had tried this solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\D','',str)
'4420700621900016'
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do split and replace.

```
>>> st =     '\n                                    4 420 700 – 6 219 000 \n        '
>>> re.sub(r'\D', '',st.split('–')[0])
'4420700'
```

or

```
st.split('–')[0].strip().replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: In Python 3 I get `44207006219000`

Comment: @KronoS it's not a actual hyphen. Just copy and paste the hyphen present in the original string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I expect only whitespaces before the firs number is it ok to use: st.split('–')[0].strip()

Comment: ya, but this won't remove the spaces present between the digits.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove all whitespace from the string, then parse the longest initial prefix of all digits, stopping if there is a non-digit (such as a hyphen). Here is my code:

```
s = (... your input string ...)

import re
s = re.sub(r"\s", "", s)    # Remove all whitespace
s = re.sub(r"\D.*", "", s)  # Remove everything starting at a non-digit
n = int(s)  # Parse the number (optional)
```

Btw, don't name your variable `str`, because it confuses with the built-in type [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).